# WPF - The property 'Content' is set more than once

Tags: xaml

I recently began working with XAML, but I encountered a significant issue when trying to use the "Content" feature. When I included the following piece of code, I received an error message[Content error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13ADP.png). Strangely, even when I removed the "Content" property from this code, the error persisted until I commented it out.
I need assistance in resolving this problem.

here is my code

```
<Window x:Class="cktest2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:cktest2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="GlowTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            <!-- Style content -->
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0" Opacity="0" ShadowDepth="0" Color="DodgerBlue" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Opacity="0.8" ShadowDepth="0" Color="DodgerBlue" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource GlowTextBoxStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                CornerRadius="5">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="CustomButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FF4CAFAD"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FF38748E"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" Opacity="0.7" ShadowDepth="3"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonTemplate" TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Ellipse x:Name="RadioButtonOuterEllipse" Width="10" Height="10" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Ellipse x:Name="RadioButtonInnerEllipse" Width="10" Height="5" Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="RadioButtonInnerEllipse" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Border Background="LightGray" Margin="-24,-13,0,0">
        <Grid>
            <Button x:Name="submitbtn" Content="Process" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,20,20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="140" Height="50" Click="submitbtn_Click" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}"></Button>
            <Label Content="Key" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="86" FontSize="20" Foreground="#333333"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="ApiKey"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,28,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="267" Height="40" Background="#F5F5F5" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" BorderThickness="1"  FontSize="20" Padding="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.42,1.333" FontFamily="Roboto"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="command" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Background="#FFFFFF" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="18" Padding="5" Height="40" RenderTransformOrigin="0.468,0.241">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="cc:sale" IsSelected="True"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="cc:void"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="cc:refund"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="ebtfs:sale"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="ebtw:sale"/>
            </ComboBox>
            <Label Content="Ref Num" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,170,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="86" FontSize="20" Foreground="#333333"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="refNumber"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="116,172,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="35" Background="#FFFFFF" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="16" Padding="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.867,0.656" />
            <RadioButton x:Name="devicePortRadioButton" Content="USB" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="440,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="devicePortRadioButton_Checked" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.486,1.174" FontSize="17" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Template="{StaticResource RadioButtonTemplate}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="devicePort" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="530,129,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="COM9" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" Height="40" Background="#FFFFFF" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="16" Padding="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.076,0.549"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="deviceName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Background="#FFFFFF" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="16" Padding="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.486,1.84" Height="40">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Verifone_P200.4" IsSelected="True"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Verifone_P400.4"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Verifone_MX915.4"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Verifone_MX915.7"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Pax_S300.3"/>
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="_deviceIp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="635,180,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="192.168.1.2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="37" Background="#FFFFFF" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="16" Padding="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.076,0.549" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            <TextBox x:Name="_ipPort" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="522,180,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="10009" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" RenderTransformOrigin="0.463,1.595" Height="37" FontSize="16" Padding="5" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            <RadioButton x:Name="deviceIpRadioButton"  Content="IP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="438,191,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.496,2.308" Checked="deviceIpRadioButton_Checked" FontSize="17" Template="{StaticResource RadioButtonTemplate}"/>
            <Grid x:Name="responseContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,20,20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="300" Height="100" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Border BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFFFFF" CornerRadius="5">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#EEEEEE" Margin="5">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="Response" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                            <Button x:Name="closeButton" Content="x" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20" Height="20" Click="closeButton_Click" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <TextBox x:Name="response" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground, ElementName=response}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Padding="5" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <TextBox x:Name="amount" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="530,28,50,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" Height="40" FontSize="20" />
            <Label Content="Amount" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="440,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="86" FontSize="20" Foreground="#333333"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button" Content="Test Key" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="350,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="70" RenderTransformOrigin="0.523,1.203" FontSize="15" Foreground="White" Click="Button_Click" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}"/>
            <!--<Button x:Name="PromptForEmail" Content="Prompt for email" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="582,274,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="83" Width="161" Click="PromptForEmail_Click"/>-->
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <!-- container for the buttons -->
    <Border Background="LightGray" Margin="660,29,10,10" Padding="10" CornerRadius="5">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button x:Name="EnableTip" Content="Enable Tip" Width="140" Height="50" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" Click="EnableTip_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="PromptForPin" Content="Prompt for PIN" Grid.Column="1" Width="140" Height="50" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>



</Window>
```